# How does find method work in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I understood the working of find method i.e. looks for the first occurrence. But I don't understand how find method is implemented at class level. Can somebody explain me the flow of this below written code? Also explain me the relation between find method and yield. How the values are passed between yield call and find call? Also explain what is the use of nil.  Thanks.

```
class Array
   def find 
         each do |value|
            return value if yield(value)
         end 
         nil
    end 
end 

[1,3,5,7,9].find {|v| v*v > 30}
```

Comment: "I don't understand how find method is implemented at class level" – Why not look it up in one of the half-dozen or so Open Source Ruby Implementations? Here's Rubinius: https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/enumerable.rb#L466-L475 , Topaz: https://github.com/topazproject/topaz/blob/master/lib-topaz/enumerable.rb#L152-L159 , JRuby: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jruby/RubyEnumerable.java#L575-L638 , IronRuby: https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/blob/ipy-2.7-maint/Languages/Ruby/Libraries/Builtins/Enumerable.cs#L145-L184

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all; you know how yield works right??

> {|v| v*v>30}
>   every item in the array is passed to this block as param `v = every element`

Explaination:
`return value if yield(value)` signifies that the current item of the array is returned from the `find` method if the block passed return `true` for the any item of the array.

So, it only returns single item; actually the first item matching the condition; unlike `select` method that returns every item matching the condition.

```
2.2.1 :030 > [1,2,3].select{|x| x>1}                                                                                                                
 => [2, 3]
```

Moreover; the `each do |value|` iterates over the the current/`self` instance of `Array` class

Comment: Yea I know how yield works

Comment: is my explanation helping you?

Comment: I am trying to understand....i have one doubt when yield(value) is called the block inside find is executed right?

Comment: actually the block you pass along with the `find` method call is executed i.e. `{|v| v*v > 30}`